# Solving $AX+X^TB=C$?

Tags: matrix-equations

Is there a name/standard algorithm to solve the following equation for $X$?

$AX+X^TB=C$

Matrices $A$,$B$,$C$ are dense, diagonalizable, nearly singular, about $1000\times 1000$ in size. I've looked through SLICOT [routines](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228824570_Evaluation_of_the_linear_matrix_equation_solvers_in_SLICOT), and nothing looked directly applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called a **T-Sylvester equation**, or *-Sylvester equation in the complex case. Solvability conditions and a pseudocode algorithm based on the Schur form are in  https://doi.org/10.13001/1081-3810.1479  . Analogous considerations for a more general class of equations and a Fortran-90 implementation of the last step of the resulting solution algorithm (the back-substitution on the triangular version of the equation) are in my paper  https://doi.org/10.1002/nla.2261 . I don't think you will find something in Slicot, because it has no immediate control theory applications.

Comment: thanks for the reference....it seems there's also a straightforward way to convert it to regular Sylvester equation and reuse those solvers

Comment: That route has dubious stability properties, though.

Comment: Always fun to find questions on here where just the right person is able to answer :-)

Comment: BTW, evaluated a couple of reduction methods here -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/t-sylvester-solve.nb . Reducing to spectral decomposition gives acceptable quality, but the speed could use improvement -- 2.9 seconds end-to-end where diagonalization takes 1.3 seconds and Shur takes 1.0 seconds